# Unable to cast the main Activity to Location Listener i.e. com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, casting, locationlistener

as i am done with my coding and tired to check whats going on with the app on emulator and stuck with an error called  `java.lang.ClassCastException` i.e 
`UserLocation` cannot be cast to `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener`

My LOG CAT AS FOLLOWS

SO guys please help me to solve this problem :D

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.example.surajnath.taproute.UserLocation cannot be cast to
>   com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener
>                                                                                       at
>   com.example.surajnath.taproute.UserLocation.startLocationUpdate(UserLocation.java:255)
>                                                                                       at
>   com.example.surajnath.taproute.UserLocation.onConnected(UserLocation.java:292)
>                                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzae.zzk(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbd.zzj(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzar.zzaht(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzar.onConnected(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbl.onConnected(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzw.onConnected(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                       at com.google.android.gm=s.common.intern
>   al.zz+ac.onC++de here`onn+ected(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                       at com.google.android.gm=s.common.internal.zzn.zzakg(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                       at com.google.android.gm=s.common.internal.zze.zzv(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                       at com.google.android.gm=s.common.internal.zzi.zzakh(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                       at
>   com.google.android.g+ms.common.internal.z+z+h.h+an+d+l+e+M+e+s+s+age(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                       at android.o+s.Handler.dispatch+Message(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                       at android.o+s.L+ooper.loop(Loo+per.java:154)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity+Thread.main(Activity+Thread.java:6682)
>                                                                                       at java.la+n+g.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at

Now link to my code is below 
https://pastebin.com/3h3CnHWb

Comment: Hi CoolBoy, can you post total code of your MainActivity for reference.

Comment: yes i have posted in a link :D 
https://pastebin.com/3h3CnHWb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong import in `UserLocation`

following

```
import android.location.LocationListener;
```

should be

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
```

you need this in your gradle dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
```

Comment: no thats my activity name :D i am not able to import import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener; why ??

Comment: do you have it in your gradle dependencies?

Comment: there no library regarding to location listener can you suggest me ?

Comment: @C0olB0y see update

Comment: the library you have shared am having already ... still having a problem ?
what to do??? @Peppermint Paddy

Comment: @C0olB0y please look at line 6 and change this like my answer says and then look for all other lines where you're using LocationListener that the reference is correct

Comment: Locational Listener causing a problem 
When i am trying to import it (alt+enter) i will add import library just before it i.e com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener
instead of import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;

Comment: Thankyou @Peppermint Problem Solved :D XD